# React native - The native module for Flipper seems unavailable

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Im using react redux toolkit. This is my store configuration.

My app doesn't start becouse this warn: The native module for Flipper seems unavailable. Please verify that `react-native-flipper` is installed as yarn dependency to your project and, for iOS, that `pod install` is run in the `ios`
directory.

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authorization from 'redux/slices/authorization';
const createDebugger = require('redux-flipper').default;

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {authorization: authorization},
  middleware: [createDebugger],
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Comment: Same for me after fresh install new React Native project v0.69

Comment: I did downgrade to v0.68, and flipper works.